# Need To select Data From One Table After Minus With One Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table and a single value

```
Table 1                
SNo           Amount     
 1              100         
 2              500         
 3              400         
 4              100 


 Value:  800
```

Now I want the result from the table is Minus the value and finally

I would like to having rolling subtraction, that is subtract the Value 800 From Table 1's first Amount and then apply it to subsequent rows. Eg:

```
for type-1
800 - 100 (Record1) =  700
700 - 500 (record2) =  200
200 - 400 (record3) = -200
```

The table records starts from record 3 with Balance Values Balance 200

```
Table-Output
SNo       Amount
 1         200
 2         100
```

that means if minus 800 in first table the first 2 records will be removed and in third record 200 is Balance

Comment: question not clear. pls ask in proper context.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking to convert something from Excel into T-SQL. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: no, everything in SQL @SQLRockstar. Datas in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a running aggregate. In your original example, you had two tables, and if this is the case, simply run a sum on that table like I am doing in the subselect and store that value in the variable I created @Sum.

The CTE calculates what the value would be as it is added together for each record, and is then added to the total calculated, and then keeps the ones that are positive.

I believe that this will fit your need.

```
DECLARE @Sum INT;
SET @Sum = 800;

WITH    RunningTotals
          AS (
               SELECT   [SNo]
                      , [Amount]
                      , [Amount] + (
                                     SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Amount]), 0)
                                     FROM   [Table1] t2
                                     WHERE  t2.[SNo] < t.SNo
                                   ) [sums]
               FROM     [Table1] t
    ),
    option_sums
      AS (
           SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [SNo] ) [SNo]
                  , CASE WHEN ( [Sums] - @Sum ) > 0 THEN [Sums] - @Sum
                         ELSE [Amount]
                    END AS [Amount]
                  , sums
                  , [Amount] [OriginalAmount]
                  , [OriginalID] = [SNo]
           FROM     [RunningTotals] rt
           WHERE    ( [Sums] - @Sum ) > 0
         )
 SELECT [SNo]
      , CASE [SNo]
          WHEN 1 THEN [Amount]
          ELSE [OriginalAmount]
        END AS [Amount]
      , [OriginalID]
 FROM   option_sums 

SNo Amount  OriginalID
--- ------  ----------
1   200     3
2   100     4
3   100     5
4   500     6
5   400     7
6   100     8
7   200     9
```

Comment: your code is wrong, try with more rows in table1...its return wrong values @jwhaley58

Comment: That appears to be working correctly now, let me know what you think.

Comment: try with more rows in table 1 its chnged all the remain rows value after the third in this example.....need to change the 3rd only remain must be same

Comment: @Suresh 2 days ago, you said this solution was working fine. If that's correct, you can mark this answer as the one that helped you, with the tick on the left. (Oh, you already did that, great!) You can always post a new question, if you have one, there is no need for comments in this question, though.