# How to select Remain values after subtract with one Fixed value

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

[Need To select Data From One Table After Minus With One Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794932/need-to-select-data-from-one-table-after-minus-with-one-value)

this is the question i already asked and this solution for one value input to table  and result. but i need this with more input values for different categories and each categories output
for eg(based of previous question)

```
Table 1                
SNo           Amount   categories  
 1              100      type1   
 2              500      type1
 3              400      type1
 4              100      type1
 5             100       type2
 6             200       type2
 7             300       type2
 8             500       type3
 9             100       type3
```

and

```
values for type1 - 800
values for type2 - 200
values for type3 - 100
```

and the output need is

```
for type-1
800 - 100 (Record1) =  700
700 - 500 (record2) =  200
200 - 400 (record3) = -200
```

The table records starts from record 3 with Balance Values Balance 200

```
Table-Output
SNo       Amount
 1         200
 2         100
```

that means if minus 800 in first table the first 2 records will be removed and in third record 200 is Balance

same operation for remain types also and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be8b7/11)

```
with T1 as 
(
select t.*,
SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [SNo])
-
CASE WHEN Type='Type1' then 800
     WHEN Type='Type2' then 200
     WHEN Type='Type3' then 100
END as Total

from t
)select Sno,Type,
        CASE WHEN Amount>Total then Total 
                                    Else Amount
        end as Amount
from T1 where Total>0
order by Sno
```

UPD: If types are not fixed then you should create a table for them, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE types
    ([Type] varchar(5), [Value] int);

insert into types 
values
    ('type1',800),
    ('type2',200),
    ('type3',100);
```

and use the following query:

```
with T1 as 
(
select t.*,
SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Type] ORDER BY [SNo])
-
ISNULL(types.Value,0) as Total

from t
left join types on (t.type=types.type) 
)select Sno,Type,
        CASE WHEN Amount>Total then Total 
                                    Else Amount
        end as Amount
from T1 where Total>0
order by Sno
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db191/3)

UPDATE: For MSSQL 2005 just replace `SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Type] ORDER BY [SNo])` with `(select SUM(Amount) from t as t1 
    where t1.Type=t.Type 
     and t1.SNo<=t.SNo)`

```
with T1 as 
(
select t.*,
(select SUM(Amount) from t as t1 
    where t1.Type=t.Type 
     and t1.SNo<=t.SNo)  
-
ISNULL(types.Value,0) as Total

from t
left join types on (t.type=types.type) 
)select Sno,Type,
        CASE WHEN Amount>Total then Total 
                                    Else Amount
        end as Amount
from T1 where Total>0
order by Sno
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db191/5)

Comment: its not fixed as type1, type2 like that....it will be any @valex  just mentioned for example

Comment: @Suresh I've added a query for that in my answer.

Comment: @Suresh Sorry I didn't notice that you have SQL-2005 version. This works under 2012 version.

Comment: i mentioned 2005 in tag....its ok....if you know the code in 2005 please help me @valex

Comment: @Suresh: I've added the version for MSSQL 2005